# What is Wrong with my Array

Tags: java, arrays

This is a home work assignment, I cant seem to understand why it doesn't work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    Shapes[] listTest = new Shapes[6];
    listTest[0] = new Circle[2.0];
    listTest[1] = new Triangle[];
    listTest[2] = new Rectangle[4];
    listTest[3] = new Trap[];
    listTest[4] = new Square[4];
    listTest[5] = new Quadrilateral[];
}

// This is the other class

public class Circle implements Shapes {  

    private double radius;
    private String name = "circle";

    public Circle(double radius){         
        this.radius = radius;    
    }
    public double area (){
        double perimeter = Math.PI*radius*radius;
        return perimeter;
    }
    public double perimeter (){
        double area = Math.PI * 2*radius;
        return area;
    }
    public String getName (){
        return name; 
    }
}
```

This is the other Circle class containing a constructor and methods that use private variables.

Comment: its saying that a bracket is expected

Comment: (Are you getting an error? Is the result not what you're expecting?)

Comment: listTest[[0] = new Circle[2.0]; (see it says another one is expected there)

Comment: What line is the error referring to?

Comment: Is this the new Java 9?

Comment: Well what you pasted in these comments has an extra bracket. [[0]. Is that how it looks in your code?

Comment: I don't know, what kind of java it is, its for the AP Computer Science class

Comment: No my code looks exactly how it is posted above

Comment: Because `new Circle[2.0]` is not valid. Use 2 instead. And you have to initialise every new array like `new example[/* an int*/]` if you want create an array

Comment: but in the other classes I declared them all as doubles wouldn't I have to call it a double here too.

Comment: `listTest[x] = new Circle(double radius);`

Comment: Your mistake is in putting square brackets

Comment: That is not how the constructor is supposed to look according to the constructor you posted a second ago

Comment: Then how is the constructor supposed to look?

Comment: Nia Please take the time to format your posts. I don't want to do it a second time for you.

Comment: @robbmj I got it go ahead and approve

Comment: nia, your constructor is fine, it is the **way** you typed it, btw im in AP Comp sci too.

Comment: @robbmj no problem mate, figured it was my turn to pitch in

Comment: nia, do you see where you are adding objects to the listTest array?

Comment: you have `listTest[x] = new shapeObject[x];` where shapeObject is a subclass of Shape. What you need to do is have `listTest[x] = new shapeObject(x);` again, shapeObject is an object of a subclass of Shape. Secondly, each of the parenthetical brackets need to have the proper parameters for that specific object

Comment: So what Ive come to understand is that the problem was in the way I bracketed

Comment: indeed, that is exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Okay, its finally working, how do I get people to stop answering my question (if you couldn't tell by now Im kinda really new to this site)

Comment: you either 1) delete the post (**I** dont recommend this but I am not reputable enough to provide a decisive delete or do not delete recommendation) 2) Scroll through the answers and click the blank check mark next to an answer that feel is the most correct. This will not prevent people from answering your question, but it shows you have selected what you believe to be the correct answer. Further answers may come in and that is fine, take a look because they may end up being helpful

Comment: @Nia forgot to tag you. btw, if you want people to see your comments on their posts, especially if the comment exchange is between you and a person who does **NOT** own the post, you have to tag them with the @ symbol followed with no spaces, by their name, just like I did with yours

Comment: @JohnnyCoder Thank You so very much, Good luck in your AP Exam (I'm pretty sure I'm going to fail) youll defiantly get a 5. Have Fun

Comment: @Nia, thank you very much. I feel like I may get a 5, but inheritance is still troubling me as well as some other aspects like inheritance through interfaces, there is just so much that I have to review. And dont worry about the exam! Im sure you will do fine, I have day where I make stupid mistakes and dont realize whats wrong with my code.

Comment: @Nia I know this coming out of the blue, but how do you think you did on your AP Comp Sci exam? We took a practice one in my class and I got a 5, but the actual screwed me up. I think I probably got a 4 but that might be a reach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is expecting Shape Object not arrays of Shapes.

For example:

it is looking for

```
listTest[0] = new Circle(2);
```

not

```
listTest[0] = new Circle[2.0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets are used to initialize an array, I get the feeling you intended to call the constructor of the `Shape` objects. Change those square brackets `[]` to parenthesise `()`.

Here is an example of what I mean.

```
public class Main {
    interface Shape {
        // ...
    }

    class Circle implements Shape {
        private double radius;
        public Shape(double radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }
    }
    // the rest of the shapes

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape[] listTest = new Shape[6];
        listTest[0] = new Circle(2.0);
        // the rest of the shapes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about how to **create objects** in java.
Based on the names: `Shapes`, `Circle`, `Triangle`. It looks like `Java Inheritance`, so I think the logic is declare an array of `Shapes` and then instantiate `instances/objects` to the array elements. When you instantiate an object, you have to use brackets **()** other than square brackets

When you use `new` operator for the classes Circle, Triangle, it is called `instantiation`, you're creating an object in memory, the Constructor of the class is invoked.

See some examples:

```
Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
Square rectOne = new Square();
Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);
```

back to your code, the `constructor` of your Circle class is

```
public Circle(double radius)
{
this.radius = radius;
}
```

therefore, to create an object, it would be `new Circle(2.0)`